# How can I build a wrapper around Entity's `DbRawSqlQuery<T>` class with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I implemented Repository pattern with UnitOfWork "my own context" for a project of mine for couple of reasons

1. Decouple my code from Entity "this may seems to be an over kill but is a requirement"
2. Have one place for all of my quires so I can reuse them

Everything is working perfectly except for a new requirement. I need to be able use my UnitOfWork to execute raw sql query.

Now, if I was to use Entity it will be easy. I can get away with something like this

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @p0", someInt).ToList();
```

Yes, I understand that that above code does not need `SqlQuery` to run. I am using `SqlQuery` here to explain what I am trying to do.

But since I am trying to decouple my code from entity, I can't use the above code in my application. Rather, my unit of work will need to provide me an API which allows me to accomplish the something. "The point here is to depend on UnitOfWork" class not Entity Context.

Here is my the contract that any UnitOfwork have to adhere to

```
public interface IUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWorkTransaction : IDisposable
{
    IUserRepository Users { get; }
    IAddressRepository Addresses { get;  }
}
```

Here is the implementation for the above contract

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly AppContext _context;
    public IUserRepository Users { get; private set; }
    public IAddressRepository Addresses { get; private set; }

```
public UnitOfWork(AppContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    Users = new UserRepository(_context);
    Addresses = new AddressRepository(_context);
}

public UnitOfWork() : this(new AppContext())
{
}

public int Save()
{
    return _context.SaveChanges();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _context.Dispose();
}

public IDatabaseTransaction BeginTransaction()
{
    return new EntityDatabaseTransaction(Context);
}
```

}

Now, I want to add another contract that forces the implementer to add ability to execute SqlQuery.

Here is what I started to do

```
    public DbRawSqlQuery<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters);
    }
```

My new contract will then look like this

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkSqlQuery
{
    DbRawSqlQuery<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql, params object[] parameters);
}
```

But since I am trying to decouple my code from Entity, I can't use `DbRawSqlQuery<T>` in my contract sine it is Entity specific. So I want to be able to build my own wrapper "generic class" around `DbRawSqlQuery` i.e `IDatabaseSqlQuery<T>` which I can use in my contract. so my new contract will be like this

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkSqlQuery
{
    IDatabaseSqlQuery<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql, params object[] parameters);
}
```

At this point I am kinda lost and not sure how my `IDatabaseSqlQuery<T>` should look like. How can I build a wrapper around `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`?